# Passing two values to directive AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have an time input , and a directive which I would like to have for custom validation. I would need to have both the start time and end time. So I pass two values using the models to the directive.

```
<input type="time" data-ng-model="activity.etime" data-ng-date="activity.stime, activity.etime" >
```

Here's my directive. When I try to access the second paramater, it gives me a undefined value ( first one is fine). Is this a wrong way to use pass two values to a directive?

```
app.directive('ngDate', function () {
    'use strict';
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, aCtrl) {              
            function myValidation(stime,etime) {        
                console.log(etime);               
            }
        }    
    };
});
```

Comment: The easy solution is to split validator into two validators `max-date=...` and `min-date=...` that can be used separately or in pair. The other way is to put data in attributes and use `attr` to read them or better to `attr.$oberve` them in that case you will have `validate-date min-date="..." max-date="..."`

Comment: What @csharpfolk said or you could also just pass in `activity` and pull out `stime` and `etime` from the object

Answer (score 1):

You really should split them into two different parameter, or just pass an object that contains those two attributes. If you really want this, you could perhaps do:

```
<input type="time" data-ng-model="activity.etime" data-ng-date="{activity.stime, activity.etime}" >
```

And then you could probably access them like this:

```
function myValidation(time) {        
    console.log(time.activity.stime, time.activity.etime);               
}
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this.

Comment: I just tried it, and it's not working.  I'm getting this in the browser console :TypeError: Cannot read property 'stime' of undefined

Comment: Well like I said, I didnt test it lol. Can u do a console.log(time, activity) so we can see whats in the variable?

Comment: Time returns etime, activity returns activity is not defined

Comment: Yeah I tried to create a jsfiddle and test this out and didnt get to work. I'm still a bit confused with directives of type 'A' and how parameters are passed with ngModel...

Comment: Considering other alternatives , I'm trying the pass the sdate using attributes, using {{ sdate }} , but is unable to convert it into a date object because the format is altered when the expression is used. So I'm hoping to get this to work